# Why does update software display no updates after updating but then thinks that the "no updates" can be installed?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I run updates each day when I start my computer.
In the last couple of weeks, after I install the updates, then the software updater flashes up as if there are more updates again -- but the update list is blank (see image).

[image: no updates, but updater wants to run again]

However, the [Install Now] button is clickable and if I click it then it goes through the update installation process as if it is doing something and then shows the same window again as if there are more updates.

Is there a problem with the current update software?
Or is this related to a bad package source I have or something?

**OS Information**

- Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS
- `uname -v` --> 44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2
- kernel : 5.19.0-43-generic
- Gnome 42.5

**Update** - Added After Comment

I ran `$ apt list --upgradable` and I see the following:

```
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.4-0ubuntu1]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please l use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

Looks like there may be a gnome update or something?

Not sure what to do to resolve this.

Comment: Next time it happens, open a terminal and run `apt list --upgradable` and then edit and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @popey Thanks, I ran that and added the output to the question.  Not sure what it means though.  Thanks for any additional help.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` if you want details about updates.  Please do not use block quotes when pasting from your terminal -- it destroys the original formatting and makes it hard to parse, and interferes with our ability to correct the formatting. Instead, click the "code sample" option in the editor or use [code fences](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164)

Comment: Running those two commands fixed it.  Thank you.  I will no longer use block quotes when pasting from terminal.

Comment: I had a similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457296/why-not-all-updates-show-up-in-software-updater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`

That fixed everything.  Now the normal software updater works fine and lets me know there are no updates.

[image: software updater - no updates]