# Should software be updating every day?

Tags: updates

It seems that every day now when I turn on the computer it says software is ready to update.   When I click for it to update, it checks and says the software is all up to date.   Or on my other computer, it updates Firefox every day or so.   That worries me.  Should it be like that?  Or am I worrying too much?

Comment: Is your problem something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470532 ?

Comment: There has been a stack of Firefox and Thunderbird updates in the last weeks. That should not be a permanent situation though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes there are software updates every day for a while, and sometimes there can be as much as 2-3 weeks between updates. In either case you should not be worried about it.